# When creating a new table how do I change the default column definition in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

When creating a new table in SSMS - right click on the "Tables" node, choose "New Table..." - the default definition for a new column is nchar(10).

Can I change that? Let's say I would like the default column definition to be varchar(5) whenever someone creates a new table.

I can't find any sort of option to change that, I'm thinking maybe it's a registry setting?

Answer (score 3):

In the Registry:

```
Path - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\DataProject
Name - SSVDefaultColumnType
```

Also look at SSVDefault*Length (e.g. SSVDefaultCharLength) to set the length.

All caveats about changing the registry apply.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that.  One small thing: when there have been multiple installationss/ versions of SSMS installed, it's necessary to ensure that they right versions of the keys are changed.

Seems obvious, but I got caught out.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't.</strike> Actually, you can: see Darryl Peterson's answer

To be honest, you're quicker to use CREATE TABLE in a query windows and type it all manually. You pick the syntax up quick enough.

To start, you could look at View..Template Explorer. There is a "Create Table" template.